# Braille printing

Tags: c#, printing, printers, braille

Does anyone have experiences with printing Braille script? I am making Braille editor and I am currently stuck with this feature. I have been trying i through PrintDialog and DocumentPaginator, but no luck. Total nonsenses came out of the printer. Has anyone done anything like that?

Comment: The answer is no doubt "yes".  Surely you can ask a better question?  You'll need to start by documenting the special printer you use to produce Braille.

Comment: If you just want black & white, create an image and print that.

Comment: Black and white? I meant Braille script printed actually as points scarved into the paper, they dont have any color

Comment: @Chuck Braille is writing for the blinds.

Comment: @Amaranth Thank you for that - I know, but the OP didn't specify a braille printer.

Comment: so noone has done anything similar? I hope that some way of normal printing will work

Answer (score 0):

A normal printer can't possibly work.  Normal printers put either ink or toner on paper.  They have no ability to emboss paper, which is what you need.  Braille printers do exist, however.  [For example](http://www.viewplus.com/products/braille-printers/)